# Commensurator of $SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ on $GL_{2}^+(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to find the commensurator of $SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ on $GL_{2}^+(\mathbb{R})$.
So far I have been able to prove that $GL_{2}^+(\mathbb{Q})$ is included in the commensurator, and my intuition tells me that this inclusion is in fact an equality, but I am not able to prove it.
Is there a way to prove the other inclusion, or to find (in case it is not $GL_2^+(\mathbb{Q})$) the commensurator in another way?

By $GL_2^+$ I mean invertible and positive determinant.

Comment: For anyone wondering what a commensurator is, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commensurability_(group_theory)#The_commensurator

Comment: The commensurator also contains the diagonal subgroup $\cong \mathbb R^\times$ of $\mathrm{GL}_2^+(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: An answer to this question was provided here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449049/commensurator-of-mathrmsl-2-mathbbz-on-mathrmgl-2-mathbbq